# c++ program execution in cmd malbehaviour

Tags: c++, time

Using cmd commands
- g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
- hello
compiles hello.cpp and runs the hello.exe program.

Normally, it used to just print 'helloworld' in the cmd window, which takes no time.

However, yesterday it started to behave differently in that after compilation, when the program is first run, another window pops out very briefly (showing 'helloworld', I can see it clearly even though the window vanishes very soon) before 'helloworld' is printed in cmd window (which is seconds later, very slow and annoying!) 
The extra window does not pop out for subsequent execution. It only pops out and causes delays during the first run.

//----------------------------------------------------------------

I have completely no idea how to make it behave like it used to, and here are my guesses of what caused it:

1. I watched porn in goolge chrome incognito window but in developer mode (had to add sci-hub extension in developer mode) and perhaps I got some virus that affected the path somehow. What's more for this guess: my google chrome is starting to crash more frequently than prior to watching porn in developer mode.
2. Compiler auto-update? But I haven't manually updated the compiler recently. It didn't ask for update too.
3. Windows update?

Anyone has any idea pls? This is very annoying bcos as quite a beginner in c++ I frequently run tests and have to go through the time delays that I have never experienced (except for programs that need longer time to execute like inefficiently-coded sudoku solver). Of course I can do it with online c++ compiler but I find notepad++ more pleasing than any other mediums.

[image]

Comment: We will need to see some code if you expect any answers.

Comment: Sorry, I have just resolved the problem, now I cant seem to find what to click to close the topic, without deleting the post. By the way the code is just a simple std::cout<<helloworld; and return 0; Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I made the program run in a crazy 10000000000 for-loop so that I could take a closer look on the popout window.

Found out that it was Avast Cybercapture (cleary written up there) scanning for zero attacks.

Disabled scanning for that directory.

Resolved. Huuray!